# Separate red color stream from Microsoft Kinect color camera video stream

Tags: colors, sdk, kinect

I want to separate red, green, blue color streams from Microsoft Kinect color camera video stream. So far, to receive the color video stream, I've used the sample code provided with Kinect for Windows SDK 2.0.

An event handler for the color frames writes the frames to a WriteableBitmap object whenever a new frame is received. How can I separate the red color stream from the color frames before they are copied to the WriteableBitmap object?

```
private void Reader_ColorFrameArrived(object sender, ColorFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ColorFrame is IDisposable
        using (ColorFrame colorFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (colorFrame != null)
            {   
                FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = colorFrame.FrameDescription;

                    using (KinectBuffer colorBuffer = colorFrame.LockRawImageBuffer())
                    {
                        this.colorBitmap.Lock();

                        // verify data and write the new color frame data to the display bitmap
                        if ((colorFrameDescription.Width == this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth) && (colorFrameDescription.Height == this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight))
                        {
                            colorFrame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToIntPtr(
                                this.colorBitmap.BackBuffer,
                                (uint)(colorFrameDescription.Width * colorFrameDescription.Height * 4),
                                ColorImageFormat.Bgra);

                            this.colorBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight));
                        }

                        this.colorBitmap.Unlock();
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Daily .NET Tips has an [article](http://dailydotnettips.com/2014/01/03/applying-rgb-color-filtering-in-kinect-color-stream-data/) about this but the code they show here is not clear enough. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppe72.png) is the result I need (and the one Daily .NET Tips show in their article).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Using this method - `colorFrame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToIntPtr` - I was not able to manipulate the actual bytes from the framedata.

You need to do it manually, and process the bytes in a for loop.

Comment: How do I store the data in bytes?

Comment: I saw this LOC in some post but this is only for WriteableBitmap objects.
 `byte* imgData = (byte*) bitmap.BackBuffer;`

But I want to store and process frame data from Kinect in bytes before writing them to bitmap object.